# trying to create monthly total using R , but Sum() gives total bigger than actual

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

my Data is called aphro and is daily precipitation

```
 Date          Terai+Siwalik    Hilly 
  <dttm>           <dbl>        <dbl>       
1 1951-01-01         1.92201    1.16439    
2 1951-02-01         0.00000    0.00000   
3 1951-03-01         0.00000    0.00000    
4 1951-04-01         0.00000    0.00000    
5 1951-05-01         0.00000    0.00000     
6 1951-06-01         0.00000    0.00000
```

I am trying to find monthly totals and my code is

```
aphro_m <- aphro %>%
mutate(month =month(Date), year = year(Date)) %>%
group_by(month, year) %>%
summarise(total_TaS =sum(`Terai+Siwalik`), Date =first(Date)
)
```

BUT the output when i checked is higher than the actual ?

Please help.

Comment: The provided data has 1 observation per month so it's difficult to check. The code seems to work for me when I add some observations.

Comment: its daily data.full data is  here. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0lyktc72ociouqr/Daily.csv?dl=0 ....please help

Comment: your `Date` column is quite confusing, it changes from day-month to month-day constantly, this must affect the lubridate functions.

Comment: Ideally you should group_by(year,month) otherwise it'll be higher

Comment: i tried that option too but still gives the same value(i.e higher)

Comment: thanks  timfaber.  maybe that is the problem. Thank u for your time

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to deal with the date issue is to make use of `parse_date_time` from `lubridate`:

```
> aphro %>%
+   as_data_frame %>%
+   mutate(Date = parse_date_time(Date, c("dmy", "mdy")),
+          Month = month(Date), Year = year(Date)) %>%
+   group_by(Month, Year) %>%
+   summarise(total_TaS =sum(`Terai.Siwalik`), Date=first(Date)) %>%
+   ungroup()
# A tibble: 768 x 4
   Month  Year total_TaS       Date
   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dttm>
 1     1  1951 16.057931 1951-01-01
 2     1  1952  5.101386 1952-01-01
 3     1  1953 45.921963 1953-01-01
 4     1  1954 29.684509 1954-01-01
 5     1  1955 20.141103 1955-01-01
 6     1  1956 26.096579 1956-01-01
 7     1  1957 70.174464 1957-01-01
 8     1  1958 26.157329 1958-01-01
 9     1  1959 72.161088 1959-01-01
10     1  1960  2.401913 1960-01-01
# ... with 758 more rows
>
```